# add key and value from different collections into dictionary

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have two array with string values, and one dictionary, im trying to add values from array1 as key and values from array2 as value in dictionary.

what is best practice in this case? 
i have tried following

```
foreach(var i in array1)
{
    foreach(var t in array2)
    dictionary.add(i.value, t.value)
}
```

Comment: The code you've shown here won't work for any number of reasons - but if you could present a short but *complete* example, including the declarations for array1 and array2, that would help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you *could* do (in .NET 4):

```
var dictionary = array1.Zip(array2, (key, value) => new { key, value })
                       .ToDictionary(pair => pair.key, pair => pair.value);
```

That basically zips together the two arrays, so you end up with a sequence of pairs. You then call the `ToDictionary` extension method, extracting the key and value from each pair.

Alternatively, you could do it the old-fashioned way:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
{
    dictionary[array1[i]] = array2[i]; // Or use Add
}
```

In both cases you should make sure the arrays are the same length, of course.

Comment: The `Zip` version must be way less efficient then the simple `for` loop. doesn't it?

Comment: @gdoron less efficient, definitely, since it allocates an instance of an anonymous type for no very good reason.  "Way" less efficient, maybe not.  It depends on how big the arrays are and how sensitive the application is to memory pressure and GC issues.

Comment: @gdoron: They're both O(n) solutions - the constant factor would be worse for the `Zip` solution, certainly... but I'd only make that a deciding factor in which implementation to use *after* proving that it wasn't good enough.

Comment: Anyway, the `For` is better, more readable and more efficient, (though less _cool_)

Comment: the first code seems work, could you please explain a little on the word pair here in your code?? kind confused

Comment: the second code does not compile, seems my array has var type which causes issues

Comment: @ikel: The array doesn't have the `var` type - it may be *declared* with that, but that's not the *actual* type. If you could show your code, it would really help... but I suspect you don't have an array of strings. If you'd post the error message, that would help. The `pair` part of the first solution is the parameter to a lambda expression. If you're not familiar with LINQ and lambdas, I'd definitely stick with the second.

Comment: @gdoron: I'm not sure which I prefer, to be honest. The first form is closer to how we'd *think* about it, I believe. It does take a certain amount of proficiency in LINQ to understand though.

Comment: @ikel `var` "type" is an implicitly type for a concrete type, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) MSDN article.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) extension method:

```
var array1 = new[] { "key1", "key2", "key3" };
var array2 = new[] { "value1", "value2", "value3" };
if (array1.Length != array2.Length) 
{
   throw new Exception("The two arrays must have same lengts");
}
Dictionary<string, string> dic = array1
    .Zip(array2, (x, y) => new { Key = x, Value = y })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

are the 2 arrays having equal length? if they are
a simple loop will do the trick,

```
for(int i = 0; i<array1.length();i++)
{
  dict.put(array1[i],array2[i]);
}
```

Comment: That even won't compile, it's not Java Script!

Comment: they are in same length, but they are var type

Answer (score 0):

another linq approach

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var pair in array1.Zip(array2, (a, b) => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(a, b)))
    ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>)dictionary).Add(pair);
```

**EDIT**

More readable:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var collection = (ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>)dictionary;
var pairs = array1.Zip(array2, (a, b) => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(a, b));

foreach (var pair in pairs)
    collection.Add(pair);
```

Comment: I would definitely rather shoot my leg then read\debug this code... **=)**

Comment: @gdoron please see the edited answer, for the sake of your leg if for no other reason.